# Disk out of space on Azure Web app on Linux

Tags: linux, azure, docker

I having trouble building and deploying new Docker containers on Azure Web App on Linux.
Error logs is claiming to be out off space, and when looking at disk usage through Kudu I can see that I'm indeed out of space.
/>df -H gives:

```
Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none        29G   28G     0 100% /
/dev/sda1   29G   28G     0 100% /etc/hosts
```

Have deployed several docker containers in web apps before and removed them aswell but it seems as they are still taking up space.
Creating a new App Service plan without anything deployed gives about 5.7G of free space.
Can't seem to run docker commands from the Kudu terminal so I'm not able to check how many images and can't figure out how to clean up space. Also sodu isn't available.
Does anyone have any ideas about how to free up some space?

Comment: Can you share your app name, [privately](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) if you like? This is currently a known issue, and can happen if you are iterating on a container and repeatedly pulling down new versions. A fix is in the works but in the meantime if you share your app name I can see if we can unblock you.

Comment: You had better use `du -sh /` to check what app cost much space.

Comment: @nlawalker I created a dummy site http://dummy2007.scm.azurewebsites.net. It's the other site in the same app plan. I have tried recreating web apps and removing them all as well.  We are deploying from a private registry if this has any implications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk was indeed full of Docker images. I have cleared them off; you should be unblocked.

This is a known issue that we will have a fix for soon. Iterating and deploying new containers is a common scenario, and the goal is that this should be completely abstracted away and you should not have to worry about this.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help! Additional questions, is there something we I can do to clear out space or do I just not iterate and deploy as often? And is there a github issue where we can track progress on the issue in the future?

Comment: Nothing you can do to clear out space yourself. A fix to mitigate this is coming very soon. We are tracking internally, there is no Github issue for this, but we'll make sure to include a mention of the fix in our release notes.

Comment: @nlawalker, getting a similar issue with my app service. How to clear old Docker images?

Comment: Can I (as a user) clear the space that old docker images use? I am currently facing the same issue. @nlawalker

Comment: this is still an issue. I filed a Support Request

Comment: @Sven, did the support team provide any guidance on what to do when this occurs?

Comment: @SamIAm Yes, you should reduce your image size. There is no other way. One App Service has 15GB of space for web app including all deployment slots.

Comment: If this helps anyone, a workaround can be done by deleting the deployment slots to free up some space. Especially if you're running a green/blue deployment strategy. Once the deployment has been swapped to the active one, deleting the old slot will free up some space since the older image will no longer be referenced and be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my coworker and I ran into this issue when pulling images from a repository on Azure. The images would not be cleared after running `docker-compose pull`, but not appear to be present on the primary node.

We would see the following upon `ssh`ing onto that node:

```
> ssh username@server.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com -A -p 2200
> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
# ...
/dev/sda1        29G  2.0G   26G   8% /
```

We would still enounter space issues. After some debugging, we found these results differed when attached to a container itself:

```
> docker-compose exec container_name /bin/bash
> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
# ...
/dev/sda1        29G  29G   0G   100% /etc/hosts
```

The following snippet worked to clear all images not in use without issue:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

Note that `--no-trunc` is required, without it docker complains that the images don't actually exist.